# Why doesn't division produce a result in shell programming?

Tags: shell

I have a shell programe, a little part of it can be seen as following:

```
count=1000
total=100000
percent=`expr $count/$total`
```

it cannot produce the division result, in the result file, only 1000/100000 was shown.

Any help? Many thanks.~

Comment: what shell language are you using?

Comment: @Justin: the question was *which* shell. Bash, dash, ash, ksh, csh, zsh, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better use [bc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_programming_language):

```
percent=$(echo "scale=2; $count/$total" | bc)
```

Comment: When I using bc as you advised, I got the following error info, what else should I add into this command? why the terminal recognize the produced .89 number as a new command?  Many thanks!!



./loop_count_reference_frame_no.sh: line 24: .89: command not found

Comment: I got it, there should no space between = and following expression.

many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to add spaces before and after '/' sign:

```
percent=`expr $count / $total`
```

But it's an integer division. So you either need to multiply $count by 100 first or use something like 'bc'.

Answer (score 3):

You should have spaces between values to be divided and / operator like here:

```
count=1000
total=100000
percent=`expr $count / $total`
#                   ^ ^ - those are important
```

Answer (score 0):

use gawk

```
count=1000
total=100000
result=$(gawk -v c=$count -v t=$total 'BEGIN{print c/t }')
echo "result is $result"
```